# Understanding multithread server/client prog in c

Tags: c, multithreading, networking, tcp

I have just started learning network concepts.

In this multithreaded server/client [program](http://www.binarytides.com/server-client-example-c-sockets-linux/), at the end there is code written for the server to handle multiple connections. My question is how server is handling multiple connections on the same socket & port(8888). One socket can accept only one client on one port at a time and what role are threads playing in this by creating `pthread_create()`?

Can someone give me a pictorial representation of sockets, ports, threads so that it will be clear for me.The more I read, the more I am getting confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When a server receives a connection request, it can complete the connection by accepting the request.
>
> A socket that has been established as a server can accept connection requests from multiple clients. The server's original socket does not become part of the connection; instead, accept makes a new socket which participates in the connection. accept returns the descriptor for this socket. The server's original socket remains available for listening for further connection requests.

In your case When new client connected using `accept`, new file descriptor created for particular client. `pthread_create` create new thread with this client file descriptor and do their job.

**EDIT1 :**

Each connection in tcp server differentiated by 4-tuple(serverip, serverport, destip, destport). Server listen on same port and ip, when client connected from different ip or different port it will be a different connection.

In your case:

- server listening on ip 10.10.62.5 port 8888.
- Two client trying to connect using port 8990 and 8991
- Client ip is different so tcp server consider it as different connection.
- Then accept system call will accept the client connection and route the client connection to new file descriptor for further operation.
- pthread_create will assign new handler with new client file descriptor.

**EDIT2 :**

From the code available in link  client program tells that,  connect to server's 8888 port. Client also need a port to connect server, you are not assigning client's port by yourself in the program. client program dynamically choose the random port. This random port would be different from 8888. By using this random port client connect to server's 8888 port.

So server and client port will be different it would be a different connection. Capture the packet using wireshark then analyze for more clarification.

Comment: Sujin:yeah i know accept() returns the socket  descriptor representing the client socket.but still how server is accepting multiple clients on its socket descriptor. Imagine server socket descriptor(here it is socket_desc is 5678 and the two clients have there socket descriptor(here client_sock) as 8990 and 8991. so it means the server desc 5678 is connected to both clients 8990 and 8991 and that  too on the same port(8888).how is this possible???I am not able to understand this.

Comment: You going to connect client from two different source port, so it will be different connection

Comment: how 2 different connection?i think u are getting confused with the numbers .5678 is SERVER DESCRIPTOR and 8990 and 8991 are CLIENTS DESCRIPTOR NOT PORTS.The port which is used is 8888 in htons(8888). and i am still not getting what is the purpose of using thread,what it actually do.Is pthread_create is like fork(),means it will create a new child process,but this child process is sharing the same address space as of parent program.so instead of calling it a process we are calling it a thread.is it like that??

Comment: how multiple client are trying to connect via different port.in the client program its clearly mentioned 8888

Comment: @ShikharDeep You are not assigning any port number for client, it assigned dynamically. client saying connect to 10.10.62.4's 8888 port.

Comment: yeah i read the basics from richard stevens it was written that we have not bind our client socket on a particular port as client generally use port assigned by kernel as client can have its socket associated with any port but In case of server it has to be a well known socket, so known servers bind to a specific port like HTTP server runs on port 80 etc while there is no such restrictions on clients.....but you haven't answered the second part of question...the thread part.what is its role??what is its purpose???

Comment: thread will handle read write operation on each client parallel using respective file descriptor

Comment: so it means creating thread is like calling a function which performs a specific task???

Comment: thanks.now my concepts are bit clear.thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

like you stuck at server side and not clear what is functionality of `accept()` at server side

So
The accept() function shall extract the first connection on the queue of pending connections, create a new socket with the same socket type protocol and address family as the specified socket, and allocate a new file descriptor for that socket.

The `accept()` function takes the following arguments:

**socket**:
    Specifies a socket that was created with `socket()`, has been bound to an address with bind(), and has issued a successful call to listen().

**address**:
    Either a null pointer, or a pointer to a sockaddr structure where the address of the connecting socket shall be returned.

**address_len**:
    Points to a socklen_t structure which on input specifies the length of the supplied sockaddr structure, and on output specifies the length of the stored address.

So while the Server IP and Server Port are constant in all accepted connections, the client side information is what allows it to keep track of where everything is going.

For example

Say we have a server at 192.168.1.1:80 and two clients, 171.0.0.1 and 171.0.0.2.

171.0.0.1 opens a connection on local port 1234 and connects to the server. Now the server has one socket identified as follows:

```
171.0.0.1:1234 - 192.168.1.1:80
```

Now 171.0.0.2 opens a connection on local port 5678 and connects to the server. Now the server has two sockets identified as follows:

```
171.0.0.1:1234 - 192.168.1.1:80
171.0.0.2:5678 - 192.168.1.1:80
```

At server side return  different descriptor for different client connections.

Comment: how 171.0.0.2 opens a connection on different port 5678.according to the program(which is given in the link).its using port 8888(in this case).so all the clients which i open in new terminals(because i am running both server and client on localhost) will use 8888.you specified the server port and client port no different but in the program on both server and client one its 8888

Answer (score 0):

That is what typical server behavior,

We do bound the socket to an interface, this can be a particular interface or for all interface INADDR_ANY.

Accept is blocking call, it accepts client request, returns new sockfd for you to handle the request.

you can see netstat results on bounded socket, you will able to see LISTEN, RECV,SEND counts on server listening socket.

You are right, all the client sockets are connected on the interface the server bound

There are limits for your total client socket file descriptors.

To increase no of clients, you can set "ulimit".

So apart from server bound socket, there will be N number of sockets those are created for each client message handling.

Have a glance at netstat output

netstat -antp --> for tcp prescribe output.